# Robot.api used to regenerate output.xml to output.xml with only passed tests

Tags: robotframework

I want to write script which based on output.xml generate me output_pass.xml without fails. My solution dosen't work:

```
class ExecutionStatus(ResultVisitor):
    def visit_test(self, test):
        if test.status == 'FAIL':
            test= None

def rm_failed(inpath, outpath):
    result = ExecutionResult(inpath)
    result.visit(ExecutionStatus())
    result.save(outpath)

rm_failed("output.xml", "passed.xml")
```

html (rebot passed.xml) generated on passed.xml contains all tests.